# how can I navigate to page but ensure that the target page will be refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I have a Login.html page from which I'm navigating to my Main.html

now when I;m doing a logout I want to navigate back to the login.html but I also want to ensure this page will be refreshed.
I don't want to disable the page cache, I just want only in this specific scenario to navigate it after refresh.

I tried the following:
`window.location.replace` but it doesn't refresh the page.
`window.location.href` - also doesn't refresh the page.
`window.location.reload()` - Refresh only the current page.

@Christof13 suggestion regarding passing a parameter is the only way I can see but it loading the page twice and it's very ugly,

any other suggestions?

Comment: Add special headers to tell the browser to not cache the page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: @christof13 Thanks but I don't want to disable the page cache, I just want only in this specific scenario to navigate it after refresh.

Comment: Have you tried window.location.reload(true) ?

Comment: @christof13 this will refresh the current page, it won't navigate me to the previous one

Comment: How about window.location.href = <url to page>?

Comment: You pass a parameter to your previous page (QueryString) and if the parameter is present you call the reload in the previous page. The drawback is that the page will be loaded 2 times.

Comment: @LaveLoos it doesn't refresh the page (see my edit)

Comment: @christof13 Yes I'm aware tot his solution but as you said the page will be loaded twice.

Comment: I don't think there's another solution unless you use dynamic pages (aspx, php,...) The cache directives are in the header and you won't be able to modify it with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was using a global variable on the window scope as the following:

on main.html:

```
window.globals.RefreshRequired = true
```

on Login.html:

```
if (window.globals && window.globals.RefreshRequired) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
```

In this way the refresh will be done if I already visited main.html during the current browser instance.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a Timeout on the logout event? This way, the location reloads only once.

```
$("#myLogOutButtonOrLink").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
        }, 1000);
});
```